# How can I get rid of this stack overflow problem in python for Kosaraju's algorithm?

Tags: python, stack-overflow, kosaraju-algorithm

I'm a new programmer, and I'm working through Stanford's algorithms course on edX.

One of the programming assignments is to find strongly connected components using Kosaraju's algorithm, on a graph with ~1,000,000 vertices. My implementation is the most basic translation from the textbook's pseudo code into Python, and it works fine on smaller graphs, so I think it's correct.

With Python's default recursion limit of 1000 it reaches the limit.

I've tried `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)`, but that doesn't help, and instead I get "Process finished with exit code -1073741571" which is a stack overflow.

I found these two pages for increasing stack size limits, but am not sure how to use either of them: [Set stack size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=vs-2019), [ulimit command](https://codehiker.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/ulimit-command/).

Another relevant bit of information is that Python doesn't optimize tail recursion, but I'm not sure that applies to my code as it currently is.

```
G = {}
for i in range(1, 875715):
    G[i] = [0]
for l in open('SCC.txt'):
    items = list(map(int, l.split()))
    G[items[0]].append(items[1])

Grev = {}
for i in range(1, 875715):
    Grev[i] = [0]
for l in open('SCC.txt'):
    items = list(map(int, l.split()))
    Grev[items[1]].append(items[0])

def TopoSort(G):
    for v in G:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            DFStopo(G, v)

def DFStopo(G, s):
    G[s][0] = 1
    global orderedVertexList
    for v in G[s][1:]:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            DFStopo(G, v)
    orderedVertexList.insert(0, s)

def Kosaraju(G, Grev):
    TopoSort(Grev)
    global numSCC
    for v in orderedVertexList:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            numSCC = numSCC + 1
            DFSSCC(G, v)

def DFSSCC(G, s):
    G[s][0] = 1
    global SCC
    SCC.append(numSCC)
    for v in G[s][1:]:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            DFSSCC(G, v)

numSCC = 0
orderedVertexList = []
SCC = []

Kosaraju(copy.deepcopy(G), copy.deepcopy(Grev))
```

Comment: Since your code works, but you need help optimizing it, you might also ask on the [codereview.se] stack site

Comment: it's very common to build your own programmatic stack instead of relying on recursion stack.

Comment: I suspect using nested lists of `int` objects uses far more memory than you really need. Consider using a `numpy` array instead.

Comment: +1 WRT @MZ's comment.  Eliminating recursion in favor of an outer loop, and using your own stack to keep track of the state of your algorithm, is how I'd approach your problem.

Comment: [Re-posted on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248900). @G.Anderson: I usually link to the [on-topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) when referring a user to a different forum, occasionally to [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)